# Show that a truncated bionamial series has a maximum

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, binomial-distribution

I have the following binomial distribution series

$$
f(n,p) = \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}p^k (1-p)^{2n-k}
$$

I want to show the following properties:

1. If $p>1/2$, $f(n,p)\rightarrow 1$ as $n\gg 1$
2. What is the value of $p<1/2$ for which $f(n,p)$ has a maximum at $n\geq 2$

How can I do it without explicitly computing the series?

For the first point, I have a non-rigorous argument. Notice that I can express the series as
$$
f(n,p) = 1-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{k}p^k (1-p)^{2n-k}
$$

The maximum of the binomial distribution is $k=2 n p$, therefore each term of the series grows as $k$ grows, if $p>1/2$. Let me estimate the biggest term for $k=n$ at large $n$ as

$$
\binom{2n}{k}p^k (1-p)^{2n-k}\Big|_{k=n} \sim \frac{(2n)^n}{n^n}(1-p)^{2n}\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^{n} = \left[2p(1-p)\right]^n \rightarrow 0
$$

since the term inside the brackets is always less than 1. Would this argument be ok? What about the second point?

Comment: The correct asymptotics of the term $k=n$ is $$
\binom{2n}{n}p^n (1 - p)^n  \sim \frac{{4^{n} }}{{\sqrt {\pi n} }}p^n (1 - p)^n  = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {\pi n} }}(4p(1 - p))^n .
$$ See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient#Asymptotic_growth).

Comment: @Gary thank you for your comment. I was missing the $\sqrt{\pi n}$ on purpose because of the exponential behavior at infinity. However, I missed the extra factor of two, which is crucial